# Loop cut not cutting correctly

Tags: edges

I'm trying to use a loop cut so that I can extrude a specific part of my mesh.
Problem is: When I use loop cut, it doesn't go all the way trough, show in the image.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: There probably are N-gons that are stopping the edgeflow. Did you inspectd the faces nearby the edgecut?

Comment: yes or some inner faces

Comment: @moonboots inner faces were the issue. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have inner faces. Delete them, otherwise Blender doesn't know where to extend the loop cut.